# Hide lists from "All Site Content" page of SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, list, sharepoint-2003

I wonder if there is a way to hide some document library lists that are shown when the user navigates to the "All Site Content" page in SharePoint, and I wonder if there is a programmatic way to achieve this. (If possible using WSS).

I need to hide many lists from this view, these lists will be accessed from the links inside a link list (this link list is the only I want the user to see).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of WSS are you asking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SPList class has a Hidden property that will do exactly what you want.

In short, you could do something like this:

```
1. Open the Site collection (SPSite)
2. Enumerate throuh all sites (SPSite.AllWebs -> SPWeb)
3. Enumerate through all lists (SPWeb.Lists)
4. Locate the lists you want to hide (base on Title or other property)
5. Set the Hidden Property to true
6. Call SPList.Update() (important!)
```